# Can xlwings return an array to a VBA variable?

Tags: vba, excel, xlwings

I am new to xlwings and have not been able to find any documentation or a way to return an array to a VBA variable.

e.g.

```
Function GetTickers() As Variant
    GetTickers = RunPython("import xcel_interface;xcel_interface.get_ticker_list()")
End Function
```

Where the returned value is something like: Array("A", "B", "C")

Answer (score 1):

`RunPython` doesn't return values, i.e. it's good for manipulating anything in a Workbook (like values of cells), but not for use within VBA or user defined functions (UDFs). The [decorator syntax](http://docs.xlwings.org/udfs.html) does what you want, but is currently only supported on Windows.

Sample Python code (that you need to import into Excel e.g. by using the add-in):

```
import xlwings as xw

@xw.xlfunc
def test():
    return [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

This will deliver you a `Variant` in VBA that you can use like this:

```
Sub arr_test()
    Matrix = test()

    For Row = 0 To 1
        For Column = 0 To 1
            Debug.Print Matrix(Row, Column)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

In Python, you could also return a NumPy array instead of a nested list: `np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

Comment: Thanks, Felix. It's not clear to me how I can import the function into Excel.  I have the xlwings.bas file (imported as a module), but I see no add-in file in the xlwings package folder (\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\xlwings)

Comment: You need at least v0.6.0. The easiest way to install is via command line client: http://docs.xlwings.org/command_line.html#add-in-currently-windows-only